# removing row based on many compound condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame with columns [ID,Date]
i want to get the id's that has occurred more than once and check whether they happend in the same date or not.
i tried this way for it.

```
#sample data
   ID        Date
0   1  2020-01-01
1   1  2020-01-01
2   1  2020-02-01
3   2  2020-01-01

#expected output
   ID        Date
   
0   1  2020-02-01
1   2  2020-01-01
```

this is what i tried

```
df.drop(df[(df['Date'] >1) & (df['ID'] > 1)])
```

but it is not giving me correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for count groups and filter if greater like `1`:

```
print (df)
   ID        Date
0   1  2020-01-01
1   1  2020-01-01
2   2  2020-01-01

df1 = df[df.groupby(['Date','ID'])['ID'].transform('size').gt(1)]
print (df1)
   ID        Date
0   1  2020-01-01
1   1  2020-01-01
```

Or you can test if duplicated by both columns in [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated(['Date','ID'], keep=False)]
```

For remove duplicated rows use:

```
df2 = df[df.groupby(['Date','ID'])['ID'].transform('size').eq(1)]
df2 = df[~df.duplicated(['Date','ID'], keep=False)]
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['Date','ID'], keep=False)

print (df2)
   ID        Date
2   2  2020-01-01
```

Comment: this gave me the rows where this condition is true. i want to remove them from the same dataframe. i tried adding df.drop at the beginning but should me an TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable .

Comment: @Mighty - I change solution with sample data, can you edit question with this data (be free modify them) and add expected ouput?

Comment: based on th sample of data you provided. the expected output that i want is 2   2  2020-01-01

Comment: @Mighty - added to answer.